# How to change youtube_dl output location with python

Tags: python, youtube-dl

I wrote a python script to download a list of YouTube URLs, and I want to change the output folder by the subject I'm downlaoding.

For example, When I'm downloading a playlist, I want the videos in this playlist be downloaded into a folder named by the current playlist. But if it's a channel, the videos inside it should go into a folder named bt it's uploader.

How do I know the URL I'm downloading is a playlist or a channel? Since the options are passed before the download starts, I can't find a way to do this.

Here is my code:

```
import sys
import yt_dlp

URLS = [
  'playlist_url',
  'channel_url',
]

dl_ops = {
  'outtmpl': 'd:/YouTube/%(uploader)s/%(title)s.%(ext)s'
}

retry_count = 0

def download_video(urls):
  try:
    with yt_dlp.YoutubeDL(dl_ops) as ydl:
      ydl.download(urls)
  except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('Interruptted by user')
    sys.exit()
  except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    global retry_count
    if retry_count == 50:
      print('Retry count exceeded')
      sys.exit()
    retry_count += 1
    download_video(urls)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  download_video(URLS)
```

Comment: You could call the `extract_info` method with `download=False, process=False` first to get some info about the URL, but the `_type` of both a channel and a playlist seems to be `playlist`.

Comment: Hey @D-Malan thanks for the help, and you're right. It seems like it's impossible to differentiate a `playlist` and a `channel` in `yt-dlp`, since they are all concerned as `playlist`. A altnaive way I find on reddit is using `playlist_title`, which outputs the current `channel` or `playlist` name, this is probably the best way for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
dl_ops = {
      'outtmpl': 'd:/YouTube/%(uploader)s/%(title)s.%(ext)s'
    }
```

You can see that in this line you specify a path to be D:/YouTube/ {uploader name} / {title of the video} . {extension that you specified}. In order to change all the videos to go into the same folder you just need to remove the "/" after the uploader so your videos don't have a seperate folder for each of the uploaders.

So if you want to have file name just as video name you will do something like this:

```
'outtmpl': 'D:/YouTube/%(title)s.%(ext)s'
```

So for a video named "Youtube vlog part 321" the file path will be:

```
D:/YouTube/Youtube vlog part 321.mp4
```

or any other format that you choose (mp3, wav, avi, mkv...).